# AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, return-value, traceback

I am pretty new to using both `SQLALCHEMY` and the `PYRAMID` web framework. I am struggling with what might be a simple fix to some, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I have looked at some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671886/attributeerror-instrumentedlist-object-has-no-attribute) [here on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882215/rendering-json-objects-using-a-django-template-after-an-ajax-call) [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733335/display-friends-name-by-flask-many-to-many-sqlalchemy), but they don't quite answer my issue.

I have a `many-to-many` relationship in my `database` table. I am trying to `return` an object (`categories`) from the parent table `assessment`. I am trying at the moment to: `return {'name': assessment.name, 'text': assessment.text, 'user': assessment.user_id, 'video':assessment.video_id, 'categories': assessment.categories.assessment_category_link}` but this doesn't work --> `'categories': assessment.categories.assessment_category_link`

I am able to return all the objects except categories. Below is the relevant error and code.

TRACEBACK:

```
 line 306, in get_assessment
    return {'name': assessment.name, 'text': assessment.text, 'user': assessment.user_id, 'video':assessment.video_id, 'categories': assessment.categories.assessment_category_link}
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'assessment_category_link'
```

SQLALCHEMY TABLE/RELATIONSHIP:

```
# MANY-to-MANY
association_table = Table('assessment_category_link', Base.metadata,
    Column('assessment_id', Integer, ForeignKey('assessments.assessment_id')),
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('categories.category_id')))

class Assessment(Base):
    # column/entity code
    categories = relationship('Category', secondary='assessment_category_link', backref='assessments')

    def __init__(self, name, text, user, video, categories):
        # CODE 
        self.categories = categories
```

The GET() method, specifically the `return` value that is throwing the error:

```
@view_config(route_name='assessment', request_method='GET', renderer='json')
def get_assessment(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_id = int(request.matchdict['id'])
        assessment = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id)
        if not assessment:
            raise HTTPNotFound()
        return {'name': assessment.name, 'text': assessment.text, 'user': assessment.user_id, 'video':assessment.video_id, 'categories': assessment.categories.assessment_category_link}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve since `assessment.categories` would return a list of `Category` objects that you need to iterate over. It is logical for such a list not to have an attribute named `assessment_category_link` (as the exception tells you), and it is not clear to me why you would want to access the association object anyway!

The relationship with the `secondary` keyword argument is **meant to** hide this complexity away so that `assessment.categories` would transparently return the list that you're after.

you can represent the categories list as you like, a suggestion for your case:

```
{...., 'categories': ', '.join([str(i) for i in assessment.categories])}
```

Comment: I am trying to render objects to print out on a JINJA template, e.g. {{assessment.categories}}

Comment: Based on your response, I am assuming I should just manually enter those into a template as HTML.

Comment: then why do you need the association object? just iterate over the categories list

Comment: Just to be clear, you are suggesting that I iterate over the JINJA template by calling the object?

Comment: represent the categories list as you like, for example you can write {...., 'categories': ', '.join(assessment.categories)}

Comment: please accept the answer or vote it up (not the comment) if you find it useful, thanks :)

Comment: This join still gives off a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Category found`

Comment: Edited according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The answer above was very close, but the working `code` is:

```
{...., 'categories': ','.join([str(i) for i in assessment.categories])}
```

As suggested by similar Stack question/answer to the same issue: [TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found)